# QML module was not found

Tags: c++, qt, qml, importerror, qt5.5

I am currently creating an application in Qt that displays a map of places. At the beginning of my QML file I import the QtLocation and QtPositioning modules:

```
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtLocation 5.15
```

In my .pro file I've got: `QT += location`.

Unfortunately, I got a message that the QML QtLocation and QtPositioning modules were not found. I decided to look for help on the internet. Unfortunately, I was still unable to fix the problem. I am a beginner in Qt and I don't know what to do. I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: You have to install that module and that depends on how you installed Qt, how did you install Qt?

Comment: @eyllanesc I installed Qt for open source users using Qt Online Installer for Windows

Comment: Are you sure you have installed Qt5? I ask because many users get confused and install Qt6. If you have installed Qt5 open the installer and enable that module

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh, I think that I have installed Qt 6.0.2